# Why my splines are moving all together when only one is selected?

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm very new to blender so sorry if I say stupid things.

I am trying to put a series of splines along a circumference (at different distances so I can't use duplication... I suppose)

For easiness I set the origin of the splines at the center of the circumference with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> *"Origin to 3D Cursor"* but when I try to "move" one single spline along the circumference (rotating with <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>) even the other splines are moving with the selected one.

**Edit:** I've switched off proportional editing but still doesn't work.

[image: Gif for reference]

Comment: You have proportional editing enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself. The problem was the *"Origin to 3D Cursor"*.

All my splines origin were on the 3D cursor so it seems Blender tought all of them were the same object...is that possible?

Anyway I solved switching to *"Origin to Center of Mass"* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. That solved my problem.

Comment: 3d Cursor doesn't make Blender to think those are the same object. It's caused by Proportional Editing (PE) - when it's on and origin point is the same for objects, the PE radius is enough to affect all the objects as it uses their origin and it's practically the same. If their origins is at their geometry PE radius in your case wasn't enough to reach origin points of objects and they weren't affected by movement.

Comment: I'm sorry @MrZak but I've disabled proportional editing and the problem was still there, only changing origin to center of mass solved my problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivyZF.gif (please note that I can move only one spline even with PE enabled)